# Getting the colour of a pixel at specified coordinate on the screen

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to get the colour of a pixel in the specified location. After some research this is what I have.

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{

    HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);
    COLORREF color = GetPixel(dc, 100, 100);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, dc);

    std::cout << GetRValue(color);
    std::cout << GetGValue(color);
    std::cout << GetBValue(color);

    return 0;
}
```

I don't get any error but there are three weird characters displayed(which I cannot seem to copy and paste here). What can I do to get the pixel colour successfully?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just a matter of the way you are printing the values. Try this instead

```
std::cout << static_cast<unsigned>(GetRValue(color)) << '\n';
```

`GetRValue(color)` etc returns a byte value, which `cout <<` is interpreting as a character. By casting to `unsigned` it forces `cout <<` to print the integer value instead.